# How to I copy the contents of a textarea to the clipboard as html?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

A textarea element contains text with html tags.

Example:

```html
<textarea>This is a <b>sample</b>.</textarea>
```

How do I copy its text to the clipboard as html? So when I paste it in e.g. MS Word, sample appears bold?

Comment: HTML is just text. It's up to the software that you paste the text into to decide what to do with it.

Comment: @tevemadar this answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Also this: [Paste HTML into Word](https://superuser.com/questions/426139/paste-html-into-word)

Comment: @Pointy: Copy text from the wysiwig (left) and the textarea (right) from https://html-online.com/editor and the result in MS Word is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function copyToClip(str) {

  function listener(e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", str);
    e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');

  document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
  
};

copyToClip(mytextarea.value);
```

Comment: @isherwood My answer is no duplicate and still my question is flagged as duplicate... Anyway, I've found an answer.